# Should I flag a crosspost for deletion?

Tags: discussion, flags, cross-posting

I bumped into two questions which are exact copy-and-paste duplicates; one on SO and one on DBA.  There's a solid community consensus that crossposts are bad, 'mkay, but should I flag one for deletion or just shed a tear and move on?

Both questions have answers.  I assume that the SO question should go, as the topic is on-topic to DBA, the more specialized site, and it has three answers there as opposed to just one on SO.

1. [SSRS Reports Manager Security Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274485/ssrs-reports-manager-security-configuration)
2. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54145/ssrs-reports-manager-security-configuration

Comment: A post from 2013 .. I'd let it go.

Comment: Now you should crosspost this on http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/ to close the circle.

Answer (score 3):

It's fine to flag those for moderator attention, but they don't really need to be deleted. We can either close the post or migrate it and ask moderators on the other site to merge them if we think it's warranted.  In either case, please do leave a link (as you did in this instance) just to let people know that the question was answered elsewhere.

Comment: What about if the question's age is beyond the 60 day migration period? I flagged a question with a custom moderator flag explaining that it's a crosspost (word for word), but I'm unsure whether I did the right thing.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ Just a regular close vote is probably better in that case, since we can't do much more than close the question. You can still use a custom flag to explain that the question is cross-posted and should be closed on SO if you don't think it will be closed otherwise.